# Problem with locating packages installed via anaconda navigator

Tags: python, anaconda

I have both Anaconda Navigator and Python 34 installed on my machine.

I wrote my script in Spyder-Anaconda Navigator.

The first line of the script starts as

```
"import pandas as pd".
```

This script works if I run it in spyder.

Then to simplify the execution, I made a .bat file and when I run that. The command prompt window opens' and throws an error saying

> pandas not found

To make sure, python can access my environment, I tried entering just python in the command prompt and it is getting recognized.

How can I fix this and make sure that the pandas or other packages which were a part of my anaconda navigator gets recognized.

The .bat file looks as below,

```
Python "\\ServerA\Python Testing Environment\Python Codes\Compare AS Report Vs DSReports.py"

cmd /k
```

Under the Environment Variables - PATH

I have these settings,

```
C:\Users\asds\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3;
C:\Users\asds\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\Users\asds\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```

Under system Variables Path,

I have these settings,

```
C:\Python34\
```

Which one I need to remove or move from one place to another.

Comment: Can you share the .bat file?

Comment: @VasanthAlagiriswamy added to the question now.

Comment: Is it possible you got 2 python versions installed? If so, check your environment variable PATH, it should point to the path of the python.exe anaconda uses. E.g. to "AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3" instead of "C:\Python\.."

Comment: @user10455554 will that change the command in my .bat file ? say here I am starting with Python, do I need to start with Conda or anything ?

Comment: If you replace the PATH variable the python-command will then use the corresponding python.exe at that location. You could also just call the python.exe in your anaconda-installation directly instead of using the "python" keyword, so you don't have to change your PATH variable

Comment: @user10455554 please take a look at the question again. I think it's the PATH and may be if you can explain that as an answer. Then I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

At first do you use only one environment?
You can check it by typing in Anaconda Prompt:

> `conda info --envs`

If only one then you can check list of installed packages in Anaconda Prompt by comend:

> `conda list -n myenv`

If you have multiple enviroments you have to activate enviroment which you concern:

> `activate myenv`

where myenv it is name of enviroment (default enviroment is called base)
Then check list of your packages for this specific environment. If there is no pandas - it means you have to install it separatelly.
More information you can find here: (Managing environments - conda documentation)

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html